# jQuery bind to many elements (on) unbind from specific element (off)

Tags: jquery

My goal is to bind to many elements on page (using on()) and then to unbind from a specific element (using off()) once it has been clicked.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: enter,
    mouseleave: leave,
    mousedown: down,
    mouseup: up,
    click: click
}, ".up_side .thumbsUp");
```

The on() function is working well, but I can't figure out how to use off() to unbind from the clicked element.

```
var click = function() {
    var thumbsUp = $(this);

    var successCallback = function(data) {
        // This is where I need to unbind the clicked element
        $(thumbsUp).off({
            mouseenter: enter, 
            mouseleave: leave
        });
    }

    $(this).castVote(direction, modelName, modelId, successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

Thanks!!!

---

### Solution

Use .data() to store a flag and check the flag before executing code. This does seems like a workaround and makes the code more brittle. If anyone finds a better way, please post back. Thanks!

```
    $(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        if ($(this).data("submitted") != true)
        {
            $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
            $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "-48px");
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        if ($(this).data("submitted") != true)
        {
            $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "0px");
        }
    },
    mousedown: function() {
        if ($(this).data("submitted") != true)
        {
            $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "-96px");
        }
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        if ($(this).data("submitted") != true)
        {
            $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "0px");
        }
    },
    click: function() {
        if ($(this).data("submitted") != true)
        {
            var thumbsUp = $(this);
            var ballotBox = $(thumbsUp).parent();
            var votingStation = $(ballotBox).parent();

            //ballotBox.hide(0, "", function() {
            var direction = $(thumbsUp).dataset("direction");
            var modelName = $(votingStation).dataset("modelName");
            var modelId = $(votingStation).dataset("modelId");

            var successCallback = function(data) {
                $(thumbsUp).css("backgroundPosition", "-144px");

                // Add flag to indicate successful vote 
                thumbsUp.data("submitted", true)

                $(this).vote_up_side('animateBallotBox', data, ballotBox, thumbsUp);
            }

            var errorCallback = function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $(this).vote_up_side('animateError', ballotBox);
            }

            $(this).castVote(direction, modelName, modelId, successCallback, errorCallback);
        }
    }
}, ".up_side .thumbsUp");
```

Comment: And... What does the code do now...?

Comment: what's the problem with this code?

Comment: The off is not working - the mouseenter/mouseleave are still firing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.off()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/) says:

> **selector** A selector which should match the one originally passed to `.on()` when attaching event handlers.

and (my emphasis)

> To remove specific delegated event handlers, provide a selector argument. The selector string must **exactly** match the one passed to `.on()` when the event handler was attached.

Hence it's not possible AFAIK to *selectively* (no pun intended) remove *some* elements from a delegated event handler.

I think your only option is to leave the event handler in place, but tag each element with some `.data()` which you use to indicate whether that particular element has already been clicked.

Comment: @waterloomatt. don't forget to accept the answer with the check sign near the answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Could you use ".one()" ?

From the docs: "To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see .one()."

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: No, I can't. The use case is a vote system that does some fancy animations on mouseenter/mouseleave. I need the events always fire until the user submits their vote. Once the vote is submitted, I need to unbind from the events. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this doesn't make sense.  When calling `off()` WITHOUT a selector, all specified events are removed, according to the official jQuery docs.  Therefore, `$(".someElement").off("click")` should unbind ALL click handlers from `".someElement"`, regardless of whether the original binding was direct or delegated.  **If it's not working, then jQuery has a bug and you should file a bug report.**

The way you're doing it with `data()` definitely will work, but I personally consider it to be an unnecessary kludge/hack.